# how to calculate time between two BigQuery records with different value, different time

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm pretty new in BigQuery and SQL and I need to calculate time duration between two records type for each user email signup and registered  were my table look like this

| date | type | phone | email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2021 14:00:00 | signup | 00112233 | new-user |
| 01-01-2021 14:01:00 | login | 00112233 | d@gmail.com |
| 01-01-2021 14:02:00 | registered | clear | d@gmail.com |

i though about doing this using OVER partition by phone but since I don't have the phone in my last event it was irrelevant.
i wonder if there a way using the second row as join table and then another last join with full table  using the email but it didn't work for me

the expected results should be

| time took (hours) | phone | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00:02:00 | 00112233 | d@gmail.com |

Comment: What dialect of SQL are you working with? You might be able to store the desired value in a variable, perform 2 requests. Once you have that `DATEDIFF (..)` might help.

Comment: It's far from clear from your example what you are asking, you mention ID it's not in your sample. Add expected results and tag your specific database.

Comment: If you have multiple sessions from multiple users and you want to avoid mixing their results together, your example data is insufficient.  What other columns do you have that enable you to differentiate between sessions or users?

Answer (score 0):

This can get really complicated if you have to follow chains -- and doing so in BQ requires looping which is a scripting function, not a SQL function.

For you particular example, you can impute the phone and email and then aggregate:

```
select min(date), max(date),
       timestamp_diff(max(date), min(date), seconds) as diff_seconds,
       imputed_phone, imputed_email
from (select t.*,
             (case when phone = 'clear'
                   then max(nullif(phone, 'clear')) over (partition by email) 
                   else phone
              end) as imputed_phone,
             (case when email = 'new-user'
                   then max(nullif(email, 'new-user')) over (partition by phone) 
                   else phone
              end) as imputed_email
      from t
     ) t
group by imputed_phone, imputed_email;
```